# Real Time Recurrent Learning (RTRL) Implementations in R

Tags: r, neural-networks, real-time

Are there any recommended RTRL packages for R? I'm specifically looking for online LSTEM or GRU neural network implementations.  Thank you!

Comment: Terrific, thank you.  That's what I was assuming...that there weren't any specialized packages to make the batch size = 1 computation/space requirements more efficient.

Comment: Glad to be of help, I've turned my comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RTRL means online learning with a recurrent neural network, you could use the R `tensorflow` interface to python Tensorflow. Or you could use the much more user friendly R `keras` ([keras.rstudio.com](https://keras.rstudio.com/)). Just train an RNN with LSTM or GRU type layer and some form of SGD, using a batch size of $1$.